# Writing To CSV file Without Line Space in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, newline

I am trying out the program for writing to a CSV file.

Here's my code:

```
import csv
#field names
fields = ['Name','Branch','Year']
# data rows of CSV file
rows = [['Stef', 'Multimedia Technology','2'],
    ['Kani', 'Information Technology', '2'],
    ['Plazaa', 'Electronics Engineering', '4'],
     ['Lizzy', 'Computer Science', '4'],
     ['Reshmi', 'Multimedia Technology', '3'],
     ['Geetha','Electrical Engineering', '4'],
     ['Keerti', 'Aeronautical Engineering', '3']]

#writing to csv file
#writing to csv file
with open('records.csv','w') as csvfile:
    #creating  a csv writer object
    csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile)
    #writing the fields
    csvwriter.writerow(fields)
    # writing the data rows
    csvwriter.writerows(rows)
```

The program runs well. But in the CSV file, there is a **blank newline space (without any entries) between each entry**. **How to eliminate that** line in the resultant CSV file?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Recommended implementation per Python3 Documentation.

```
with open('records.csv','w', newline='') as csvfile:
    #creating  a csv writer object
    csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile)
    #writing the fields
    csvwriter.writerow(fields)
    # writing the data rows
    csvwriter.writerows(rows)
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer

Comment: what to do in case of python 2.7 . It showing newline nor defined

Comment: If using 2.7, add `lineterminator` argument to `csv.writer`. Example: `writer = csv.writer(f, lineterminator='\n')`

Answer (score 1):

Method 1 So when ever i write csv files spaces between lines are created and when reading the files they create problems for me So here is how i solved it

```
with open("Location.csv","r") as obj:
            reader=csv.reader(obj)
            for lines in reader:
                try:
                    print(lines["Code"])
                    print(lines["Key_num"])
                except TypeError:
                    pass
```

Method 2
Or even simpler you can use Dictreader works fine without error even if spaces are preset

```
with open("Location.csv","r") as obj:
              reader=csv.DictReader(obj)
              for lines in reader:
                    print(lines["Code"])
```